# How to check variable value in where clause in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

In SQL

DECLARE @Search VARCHAR(100) = ''

SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE @Search = '' OR FirstName like '%'+ @Search +'%'

Please help me out on this query, how to write this query in mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Well you will have to use [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator in mongodb in order to achieve that

your query would be some what like this

```
db.customers.find({"FirstName": /.*SearchTerm.*/})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply....my actual query is if search variable value is blank like '' then it should return all records and if search is not blank then should return only those which have mentioned in the variable value.

Comment: @KamaleshChettiyar: I am not sure you can achieve that in MongoDB. if you want all the documents you have to go for db.customers.find(). There is no other option, you will have to adjust your query programmatically.